# how to detect memory leak in tbbmalloc

Tags: c++, windows, tbb, memory-leak-detector

as you know,
TBBmalloc doesn't return memory blocks to system.
I'm using Visual leak detector to detect memory leak on my project.
and I wonder how to detect memory leak in TBBmalloc.
I want to see the callstack which of leaked memory blocks when program has exited like Visual leak detector do.

Is there another great tool for detection?
, how to write code easily to detect memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

Intel Inspector able to detect memory leaks when TBBmalloc is used.

*TBBmalloc doesn't return memory blocks to system.*

It does since TBB 4.0. Hope your version is more fresh.

Comment: TBBMalloc still does not return small size object, which is under 8K bytes, until program exit.

Comment: Yes, and this is because recently released object is most probably hot in a CPU cache, and chances are high that it will be reused very soon. Allocators are constantly balancing between performance and memory consumption, and automatic decision can't be 100% optimal. TBBmalloc has sophisticated caching, it can be (mostly, with some exceptions) cleaned via

  scalable_allocation_command(TBBMALLOC_CLEAN_ALL_BUFFERS, 0)

Strictly speaking per-thread caches of free objects are cleaned on thread termination, not on program exit.

Comment: first of all, thank you for your reply. I did not mean that tbbmalloc has a problem. I know what you said and I love tbbmalloc. I just want to detect memory leak on my application with tbbmalloc when I don't return small size object to tbbmalloc using scalable_free()